# Attempting to remove element and reorder elements in resulting document

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML and XSLT.

1. I am attempting to exclude the NotUsed2 element from the resulting document.
2. I need to reorder the resulting so that AutoTypesetInfo follows NotUsed3.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<Plan xmlns="http://www.ccieurope.com/xmlns/CCIPlanner">
        <Header>
            <Update>0</Update>
            <NewsPaper>Pub1</NewsPaper>
            <Date>080818</Date>
            <Zone>MAIN</Zone>
            <Edition>1st</Edition>
            <Pages>26</Pages>
            <Section>A B C </Section>
            <Number>08082018</Number>
            <Format>
                  <Height>21.70i</Height>
                  <Width>9.87i</Width>
            </Format>
            <PrintingInfo/>
            <Version/>
            <Config/>
            <Default/>
            <FileFormat>2.0</FileFormat>
            <IssueName/>
        </Header>
        <Page>
            <PhysicalBook>A</PhysicalBook>
            <BookPageNumber>1</BookPageNumber>
            <Desk>A</Desk>
            <SubDesk/>
            <SpreadPage>0</SpreadPage>
            <Status/>
            <Deadline>0708182230</Deadline>
            <PagePrintInfo/>
            <Cmyk>CMYK</Cmyk>
            <Spot1/>
            <Spot2/>
            <Spot3/>
            <CyanFilm/>
            <MagFilm/>
            <YelFilm/>
            <BlackFilm/>
            <Spot1Film/>
            <Spot2Film/>
            <Spot3Film/>
            <PageId>MAIN@F</PageId>
            <TemplatePage>
                  <Content>c@FolioStandard@i@</Content>
                  <Layout></Layout>
            </TemplatePage>
            <ProdForm/>
            <TextSourceDir/>
            <TextSourcePage/>
            <RunningPage/>
            <CmyDeadline/>
            <ColorGrp/>
            <AdRules>1</AdRules>
            <CustChar/>
            <CustDate/>
            <Active>1</Active>
            <NoMaster>0</NoMaster>
            <Cust2/>
            <PageType>EditorialOnly</PageType>
            <Cust4/>
            <Cust5/> 
            <Cust6/>
            <Cust7/>
            <Cust8/>
            <Cust9/>
            <Cust10/>
            <Desk2/>
            <Desk2NewsHole/>
            <Desk2Placement/>
            <Cust11/>
            <NotUsed2/>
            <NotUsed3/> 
                <Ad>
                    <BookingNumber>12345</BookingNumber>
                    <Description>Desc1</Description>
                    <AdRelatedInfo> </AdRelatedInfo>
                    <FirstPubDate>080818</FirstPubDate>
                    <LastPubDate>080818</LastPubDate>
                    <Customer>Customer</Customer>
                    <AdColor>Proces</AdColor>
                    <AdWidth>710.9</AdWidth>
                    <AdHeight>144.0</AdHeight>
                    <MatType>EPS</MatType>
                    <AdType>0</AdType>
                    <AdPos>

                          <XPos>0.00</XPos>
                          <YPos>1404.03</YPos>
                    </AdPos>
                    <AdProdInfo/>
                    <AdNotUsed2/>
                    <AdNotUsed3/>
                    <AdCust1/>
                    <AdCust2/>
                    <AdCust3/>
                </Ad>
          <AutoTypesetInfo>0:5-60</AutoTypesetInfo></Page>
        <Page>
            <PhysicalBook>A</PhysicalBook>
            <BookPageNumber>2</BookPageNumber>
            <Desk>A</Desk>
            <SubDesk/>
            <SpreadPage>0</SpreadPage>
            <Status/>
            <Deadline>0708182230</Deadline>
            <PagePrintInfo/>
            <Cmyk>CMYK</Cmyk>
            <Spot1/>
            <Spot2/>
            <Spot3/>
            <CyanFilm/>
            <MagFilm/>
            <YelFilm/>
            <BlackFilm/>
            <Spot1Film/>
            <Spot2Film/>
            <Spot3Film/>
            <PageId>MAIN@1</PageId>
            <TemplatePage>
                  <Content>c@FolioStandard@i@</Content>
                  <Layout></Layout>
            </TemplatePage>
            <ProdForm/>
            <TextSourceDir/>
            <TextSourcePage/>
            <RunningPage/>
            <CmyDeadline/>
            <ColorGrp/>
            <AdRules>1</AdRules>
            <CustChar/>
            <CustDate/>
            <Active>1</Active>
            <NoMaster>0</NoMaster>
            <Cust2/>
            <PageType>Mixed</PageType>
            <Cust4/>
            <Cust5/> 
            <Cust6/>
            <Cust7/>
            <Cust8/>
            <Cust9/>
            <Cust10/>
            <Desk2/>
            <Desk2NewsHole/>
            <Desk2Placement/>
            <Cust11/>
            <NotUsed2/>
            <NotUsed3/> 
                <Ad>
                    <BookingNumber>152345</BookingNumber>
                    <Description>Description</Description>
                    <AdRelatedInfo> </AdRelatedInfo>
                    <FirstPubDate>080818</FirstPubDate>
                    <LastPubDate>080818</LastPubDate>
                    <Customer>Customer</Customer>
                    <AdColor>000K</AdColor>
                    <AdWidth>351.9</AdWidth>
                    <AdHeight>360.0</AdHeight>
                    <MatType>EPS</MatType>
                    <AdType>0</AdType>
                    <AdPos>

                          <XPos>0.00</XPos>
                          <YPos>1188.03</YPos>
                    </AdPos>
                    <AdProdInfo/>
                    <AdNotUsed2/>
                    <AdNotUsed3/>
                    <AdCust1/>
                    <AdCust2/>
                    <AdCust3/>
                </Ad>
                <Ad>
                    <BookingNumber>12345</BookingNumber>
                    <Description>Description</Description>
                    <AdRelatedInfo> </AdRelatedInfo>
                    <FirstPubDate>080818</FirstPubDate>
                    <LastPubDate>080818</LastPubDate>
                    <Customer>Customer</Customer>
                    <AdColor>Proces</AdColor>
                    <AdWidth>351.9</AdWidth>
                    <AdHeight>360.0</AdHeight>
                    <MatType>EPS</MatType>
                    <AdType>0</AdType>
                    <AdPos>

                          <XPos>358.99</XPos>
                          <YPos>1188.03</YPos>
                    </AdPos>
                    <AdProdInfo/>
                    <AdNotUsed2/>
                    <AdNotUsed3/>
                    <AdCust1/>
                    <AdCust2/>
                    <AdCust3/>
                </Ad>
          <AutoTypesetInfo>0:5-60</AutoTypesetInfo>
        </Page>

</Plan>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:cci="http://www.ccieurope.com/xmlns/CCIPlanner"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl cci"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- If element name match on NotUsed2, exclude from result -->  
  <xsl:template match="NotUsed2" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected in the resulting Page node:

```
<Page>
    <PhysicalBook>A</PhysicalBook>
    <BookPageNumber>1</BookPageNumber>
    <Desk>A</Desk>
    <SubDesk/>
    <SpreadPage>0</SpreadPage>
    <Status/>
    <Deadline>0708182230</Deadline>
    <PagePrintInfo/>
    <Cmyk>CMYK</Cmyk>
    <Spot1/>
    <Spot2/>
    <Spot3/>
    <CyanFilm/>
    <MagFilm/>
    <YelFilm/>
    <BlackFilm/>
    <Spot1Film/>
    <Spot2Film/>
    <Spot3Film/>
    <PageId>MAIN@F</PageId>
    <TemplatePage>
          <Content>c@FolioStandard@i@</Content>
          <Layout></Layout>
    </TemplatePage>
    <ProdForm/>
    <TextSourceDir/>
    <TextSourcePage/>
    <RunningPage/>
    <CmyDeadline/>
    <ColorGrp/>
    <AdRules>1</AdRules>
    <CustChar/>
    <CustDate/>
    <Active>1</Active>
    <NoMaster>0</NoMaster>
    <Cust2/>
    <PageType>EditorialOnly</PageType>
    <Cust4/>
    <Cust5/> 
    <Cust6/>
    <Cust7/>
    <Cust8/>
    <Cust9/>
    <Cust10/>
    <Desk2/>
    <Desk2NewsHole/>
    <Desk2Placement/>
    <Cust11/>
    <NotUsed3/> 
  <AutoTypesetInfo>0:5-60</AutoTypesetInfo>
        <Ad>
            <BookingNumber>12345</BookingNumber>
            <Description>Desc1</Description>
            <AdRelatedInfo> </AdRelatedInfo>
            <FirstPubDate>080818</FirstPubDate>
            <LastPubDate>080818</LastPubDate>
            <Customer>Customer</Customer>
            <AdColor>Proces</AdColor>
            <AdWidth>710.9</AdWidth>
            <AdHeight>144.0</AdHeight>
            <MatType>EPS</MatType>
            <AdType>0</AdType>
            <AdPos>

                  <XPos>0.00</XPos>
                  <YPos>1404.03</YPos>
            </AdPos>
            <AdProdInfo/>
            <AdNotUsed2/>
            <AdNotUsed3/>
            <AdCust1/>
            <AdCust2/>
            <AdCust3/>
        </Ad>
</Page>
```

I can't get the code to exclude the NotUsed2 element.
I'm not sure where to begin to tackle reordering the elements within  nodes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NotUsed2` is not being removed because you have not accounted for the fact the element is in a default namespace in the XML. Your XSLT is looking for an element with no namespace.

You have declared the relevant namespace in your XSLT, so you just need to use the relevant prefix in the template match

```
<xsl:template match="cci:NotUsed2" />
```

For moving `AutoTypesetInfo` after `NotUsed3` you should have a template that matches `NotUsed3` where you can copy both the matched node, and the `AutoTypesetInfo`

```
<xsl:template match="cci:NotUsed3">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../cci:AutoTypesetInfo" />
</xsl:template>
```

You would also need a template to ensure the `AutoTypesetInfo` still doesn't get copied in its current position too

```
<xsl:template match="cci:AutoTypesetInfo" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:cci="http://www.ccieurope.com/xmlns/CCIPlanner"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl cci">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- If element name match on NotUsed2, exclude from result -->  
  <xsl:template match="cci:NotUsed2" />

  <xsl:template match="cci:NotUsed3">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="../cci:AutoTypesetInfo" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cci:AutoTypesetInfo" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does assume `NotUsed3` is always present. If not, change the last template to this to ensure the original `AutoTypesetInfo` is not removed in this case.

```
<xsl:template match="cci:AutoTypesetInfo[../cci:NotUsed3]" />
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to mark this.  Thanks for the guidance.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:cci="http://www.ccieurope.com/xmlns/CCIPlanner"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl cci"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- If element name match on NotUsed2, exclude from result -->  
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='NotUsed2']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```